# How to add multiple round holes to a mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I need to add several holes into a mesh, like you would have on the top of a salt shaker:

[image]

I tried using the `boolean` modifier, as well as `knife project` with a circle, before I realized that the `subdivision surface` modifier was already rounding square shapes into circles.

With this I can just delete a face without any supporting edges that will look like a circle, and this works fine for 1 hole. However when I try to have several holes and apply the `subdivision surface` modifier the geometry does crazy things that I am not understanding:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am unsure how to proceed to have several holes in this mesh.